# Running a AsyncTask to produce 2 different results

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a AsyncTask that is started by a user button click.

one of the processes running is producing a zip file from a zipOutputStream.
OnPostExecute is called to email result.

I want to also send the results (3 strings) to my sql table. I have made it work already using nameValuePairs and httppost. I stuck it in the middle of my for loop and it sends the strings to sql as it builds the zip file.

Problem is that its about 5 times slower than it was before.

How can I work around this?

I thought about building an array and letting my main activity doing the processing in the background. But i cant figure out how to get the array list to execute AFTER the onPostExecute is called. I have to call the method before the return zipfile is executed.

Sorry for the lack of code but im trying to protect my source :(

like i said, an ideal situation would be to have the user process the zipfile quickly and email results while the post to sql works in the background so the user doesn't even know about it. Not that im trying to hide it, its just a background task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ideas (in the order I like them best):

1. Queue the results (hashmap, arraylist, dictionary, etc) while your
   async task is running. Batch upload the queue when the user is not using the app. 
   Fire off a async task when onPause executes.
2. Queue the results (hashmap, arraylist, dictionary, etc) while your
   async task is running. In the "onPostExecute" of the first async
   task spin off another async task to do a batch upload.

Have you considered using [robospice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice) to handle your post requests?

Comment: i went ahead and ran another "silent" asynctask after the first on had completed. seems to work well. However, i really like your suggestions and going to look into them